# What word can be used for a person who expects quick results?

Tags: word-request, vocabulary

As the title says I want to know a single word that can be used for a person who expects immediate results?

Comment: Tags should be used to explain what the question is about, not what kind of answer you will accept. If there is some restriction on the type of word you would like, you should [edit] that explanation into your question. There is more [information about tagging](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) in the [help].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off the top of my head I'd say "impatient", although that carries a negative connotation.

You might want to give a little more context in order to find a more suitable word or phrase.

Depending on the context, those might fit:

- keen
- insistent
- pushy
- longing

Comment: Actually we were discussing about something that relates to human nature that is, he/she expects to get result as soon as he starts working on something, without continuous effort.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can be `eager` - at least it will be suitable for the one expecting quick response.